# Capture output from subprocess with a timeout set

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I am using `subprocess.run` to run a command and capture the output like so:

```
proc = subprocess.run([commandAndFlags], capture_output=True)

if proc.stdout:
    print('stdout:', str(proc.stdout))
if proc.stderr:
    print('stderr:', str(proc.stderr))
```

I would like to add a timeout, but still capture any output sent to stdout/stderr before the timeout goes off.

However, if I simple add the timeout and wrap it in a try/except, I cannot capture the subprocess output.

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.run([commandAndFlags], capture_output=True, timeout=2000)
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('Timeout!!')

if proc.stdout:
    print('stdout:', str(proc.stdout))
if proc.stderr:
    print('stderr:', str(proc.stderr))
```

Now `proc` is not defined when I try to print stdout/stderr.

How can I set a timeout but still capture any output that was printed before the timeout?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can still use the `capture_output` attribute from your original code, and when the `TimeoutExpired` exception is thrown, you can collect `stdout` and `stderr` from there. For example:

```
try:
    proc = subprocess.run([commandAndFlags], capture_output=True, text=True, timeout=2000)
    outs = proc.stdout
    errs = proc.stderr
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired as timeErr:
    outs = timeErr.stdout
    errs = timeErr.stderr
```

Comment: I like the approach, but `text=True` has no effect on the `timeErr` data. I used `outs = timeErr.stdout.decode()`.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually I figured out that you can pass files directly to `subprocess.run`.

```
outfile = 'outfile.txt'
errfile = 'errfile.txt'
try:
  proc = subprocess.run([commandAndFlags], timeout=2000
                        stdout=open(outfile, 'w'), stderr=open(errfile, 'w'))
except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
    print('Timeout!!')

# check if outfile/errfile files exist and print contents
```

subprocess will save stdout/stderr directly to a file that can be viewed later, regardless of if the subprocess was stopped by a timeout.